# Opening raw data stream (such as tcpdump) in portaudio

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I would like to open a raw data stream from program such as tcpdump in portaudio, what would be your advice? Didn't found much in documentation about receiving passed data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but, I'd write a c or c++ program that takes a stream through the standard in and passess data from that stream to the portaudio buffers in the pa callback. I'd then call the program like:

```
$tcpdump <params> | my_pa_based_program
```

Comment: thanks, I already managed to implement pcap library into my portaudio app.